# Why does mySQL include client_num columns with value zero / 0 in my query

Tags: mysql

In 2 tables I query for countries or client numbers like this :

```
SELECT 
client_num, 
countries.en as country, 
FROM clients, countries 
WHERE clients.country_id = countries.ID
AND ( countries.en =:keyword 
OR    client_num =:keyword )
```

The keyword let's say is `Spain`. For this I get a result of 150 entries. But in the table are only 140 countries named `Spain`. The reaseon why I get 10 more is because those entries have values of `zero / 0` in their `client_num` column. The column is of type `INT` whith 0 as default.

I can exclude those wrong entries like this :

```
SELECT 
client_num, 
countries.en as country, 
FROM clients, countries 
WHERE clients.country_id = countries.ID
AND (   countries.en =:keyword 
OR    ( client_num != 0 AND client_num =:keyword )  )
```

Now I get the correct result with 140 entries. But why ?

EDIT :

Adding and refering to @ Kamil G. answer : The 10 more matched entries do not have `Spain` in their respective countries.en column.

EDIT 2 :

I must add that clients and countries come from 2 different DB's. I left it out to make it more simple. So here is the complete query :

```
SELECT 
  db_one.clients.client_num , 
  db_two.countries.en as country , 
FROM  db_one.clients , db_two.countries 
WHERE db_one.clients.country_id = db_two.countries.ID
  AND ( db_two.countries.en =:keyword 
  OR  ( db_one.client_num != 0 AND db_one.client_num =:keyword )  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your query is that in the test `client_num = :keyword`, you are testing an integer against a string. The string is then converted to the integer 0, and the test succeeds.
In order to solve this, you have to only compare `client_num` to `:keyword` when `client_num` is non-zero or to convert `client_num` to a string before doing the comparison (which will work even when `:keyword` has the value "0"):

```
SELECT client_num, countries.en as country, 
FROM clients INNER JOIN countries ON clients.country_id = countries.ID
WHERE (countries.en = :keyword OR CAST(client_num AS CHAR) = :keyword )
```

EDIT:
As there seem to be no connection between `countries.en` and `client_num`, it would be better to have separate variables for these in the query, like this:

```
SELECT client_num, countries.en as country, 
FROM clients INNER JOIN countries ON clients.country_id = countries.ID
WHERE (countries.en = :keyword OR client_num = :clientnum )
```

If `:keyword` comes from a search form, this involves the addition (and validation) of a new field. The introduction of a new field can be avoided by setting `:clientnum` in the code prior to executing the search, like this (pseudocode):

```
IF is_numeric(keyword) THEN
   clientnum = keyword
ELSE
   clientnum = -1
```

Similar code should be used for validation of a separate `clientnum` field in order to avoid the original problem (that an empty/non-numeric value is converted to 0).

Comment: This seems the answer and the solution. Though it leeds me to change the `client_num` from `INT` to `char(5)` and in the test it works without casting (obviously). So what is more clever now ? Keeping `client_num` an `INT` to save space or declare it as `char(5)` to speed up performance by avoiding casting in the query ? Info : client_num is widely spread as a reference in my application.

Comment: I would  keep client_num as an int, and also consider introducing a separate variable to compare it to instead of using :keyword for two different purposes.

Comment: OK - but why ? Can you explain it ?

Comment: 1. countries_en and client_ref don't seem to be related. 2. Int is the obvious choice for a numeric key field. 3. First make it correct, then fast. (i.e. don't optimize until performance is an issue, then explore the available options)

Comment: Ok, logic so far. What do you mean exactly with introducing a sep. variable ? Could you describe this in a complete sep. answer - if possible ?

Comment: got it - but implies more effort in coding, does'nt it ? Casting looks more straight forward for me. Anyway, wouldn't be the solution not to convert non-numeric values to 0 at all ?

Comment: Yes. Most solutions involve more coding. The simplest solution would be to avoid zeroes in the `client_ref` column, _e.g._ by changing the default to -1.

Answer (score 1):

You have 10 values with `0` in the `client_num` column, but their `country_id` matches `id` from `countries` which have `en` column matching the specified `:keyword` condition, so they are not discarded from the output, even though `client_num` doesn't match the `:keyword` since you have an `OR` operator.

Run below query to find out what's going on:

```
SELECT 
  client_num, 
  countries.en as country, 
FROM clients
JOIN countries ON clients.country_id = countries.ID
WHERE 
  countries.en = 'Spain'
  AND client_num = 0
```

I've also replaced old fasioned joining in WHERE clause with explicit `JOIN` and you are advised to do the same.

Comment: I changed the old fashioned joining. When I use the WHERE clause as you wrote then I get `no` results at all, because there is no column with `Spain` and `client_num = 0`. If I negate that to `!=0` then I get again 10 more entries.

Comment: @Ben you need to attach your data to your question because I'm unable to reproduce your case if I understand correctly. Please consider wrapping it up in a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) script

Comment: I completed the code above, see EDIT 2. I am not firm with sqlfiddle. Will take a while to set it up, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your second query i.e.

```
SELECT 
client_num, 
countries.en as country, 
FROM clients, countries 
WHERE clients.country_id = countries.ID
AND (   countries.en =:keyword 
OR    ( client_num != 0 AND client_num =:keyword )  )
```

in the OR part is neglecting those entries whose client_num is zero/0

this is done in this part

```
client_num != 0
```

so those entries with default value do not pass the filter

Comment: @ z_dna : Well ( `client_num !=0 AND client_num =  'Spain' )` works. Both have to be true to match the `:keyword`. Client_num is of type INT, so there could also be a value of 0, or not ? Indeed there is. What is your point exactly ?